# using script to row count ssis 2012

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis-2012

I have a large number of xls files and I would like to have a row count for each of the files to store in a report file which I will also use as a cache lookup in later stages. 
I dont want to create a source and rowcount component for each file (although I do have all the connection managers setup for them) Can this be done in a script?.

Answer (score 0):

You can yes - create your script in SSIS and run some code like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715926/c-getting-the-number-of-rows-columns-with-excelpackage)

That said, it would probably be quicker to load it into a temporary table and then ditch the data - you can use a For Each to iterate through a folder location.

Points to note:

- Different versions of Excel may have different ways of opening worksheets etc. Do you know that your version will always be (for example) Excel 2003?
- A 64-bit instance of SSIS will not be able to access an Excel spreadsheet using 32-bit drivers.

Comment: I managed to get a basic script loop and count working but performance was pretty rubbish. In the end it was easier, perhaps not cleaner looking to just read a column from each file into a rowcount and then use a script to build the report using the variables